# Pilot light, logic and Opto issues

Tags: power-supply, three-phase, power-engineering, indicator

First time poster, long time lurker.

I’m an electrician to start with, so excuse my lack off EE expertise. Trained in the elevator industry but now float around a few industries.

I’m putting together a pilot light for some 3ø switch gear, I have a basic idea of the function and have tested a few variations and it works in principle. First let me start with the design criteria.

4 Led indicators, all LEDs to be isolated from mains potential. 1 LED per Phase to indicate power present. 4th led is to flash if Neutral, earth or any of the Phases are open circuit/disconnected.

In my PoC stage i’m connecting the three phase LEDs each to a phase and Wye point via a 68k resistor, a diode and a bypass diode (for return path). I then connect another similarly arranged (sans the bypass diode) LED between the Neutral & Earth and the Wye point. This basic circuit gives me effective indication of 3 phases, earth and neutral continuity, provided that I have at least 2/5 inputs hi.

I then moved onto a rectified version, with the three phases getting full bridge rectification (with respect to the Wye point) with earth and neutral getting half wave via a few resistors.

I have mains isolated 12v supply available via seperate means.

I have a basic 555 timer for the flashing LED, which is bread board tested and works fine.

Im using a quad NAND IC to get the 555 circuit to flash in the event any of the 5 inputs goes low. However I’m struggling with the logic and the opto couplers (pc817).

The optos drive an LED on the emitter no problem, so they seem to be switching just fine, but they drop ~9v between Collector and emitter (even without the led in circuit). Not sure if this the problem or just one of many.

I’ve done quite a bit of trial and error and I just can’t figure it out. Should I be driving the logic via transistors? Is there a much simpler/easier way to do this?

I’m trying to avoid using any chips that need programming. The idea is it needs to be serviceable by anyone who can get hold of basic parts and tools. Also trying to keep parts count to an absolute minimum.

The LED display will be on a seperate board, so first attachment is a basic signal flow, the second shows an expanded view.

Thanks in advance everyone and happy holidays!
[image][image]

Comment: How does current flow through the opto transistor? The emitter goes through a resistor into a very high impedance cmos logic input. The resistors should go to gnd.

Comment: @stage electrics - even using your relay concept, the logic gate provides next to no load. Placing the resistor from the opto transistor E to gnd provides a load. The logic input connects to the opto E.

Comment: So for the sake of clarity, in my circuit I have a resistor between the logic input and the opto E. But the resistor should be from emitter to gnd, and emitter drives logic input. Can I still use the emitter to drive a non-inverted LED?

Comment: @Andyaka "3ø" is electrician short-hand for three phase

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to use the Earth wire as intentional return path - imagine tripping an RCD ot GFCI immediately. CMOS logic chip inputs also don't work by being connected to supply voltage or disconnected, they work by being connected to either supply voltage or ground. And CMOS logic chip outputs are not powerful enough to run loads like NE555 blinking a LED, even a LED by itself may barely work.

Comment: @justme the earth is not a return path. I specifically made this part of the circuit half wave to avoid this. In my part of the world, high current 3ø outlets do not use gfci/rcd so nuisance tripping is not an issue. Thanks for the tip about the low powered outputs of the logic though! Much obliged

Comment: what connects to CN3?

Comment: Breakout board for the 4x LED

Comment: Not on the schematic, so it doesn’t exist! You’ve got leds on the inputs, so why on the outputs?

Comment: I thought I made that clear in the second attachment. Sorry for the ambiguity, I don’t know what I don’t know so it’s hard to judge what information is pertinent and what is implied. LED on input are not isolated from mains. Simply there to help me verify designs as I’m learning on the go

Comment: There are much better Quad opto IC's with Darlington (2stage) buffers  that are cheap, and only need 1 mA to drive output indicator LEDs with 6 mA which ought to be plenty bright if using ultrabright LEDs.  So with 120Vrms  168Vp your 150K resistors can pulse the LED's and logic with 1V low https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/optoisolators-transistor-photovoltaic-output/903?s=N4IgjCBcpgnAHLKoDGUBmBDANgZwKYA0IA9lANogAMIAusQA4AuUIAykwE4CWAdgOYgAvsQBMVWAGZkINJCx4ipCiAAsdRi0ggAkryb5%2B%2BTsOIBaUTLlcArkrKRKAVjpC3QA  then no changes are needed. Current Gain > 6 rather than 10%

Comment: @Tony Stewart thank you for your input. Would you mind elaborating on that? Im not embarrassed to say, but I don’t really understand how a Darlington output solves my problem. In my region we would see 230-245v. I would require 5ch would I not?

Comment: Yes, so 2 IC's can do 8 channels 3unused.  I would make a small change between zener 4.7V to opto by adding (4.7-1.2V)/1mA= 350 ohm current limiting and don't use LED indicator in series , For 240Vac change 150K to 300K and use C= T/R = 50 ms/300k= 1/6 uF or 150 nF

Comment: Thanks again Tony. I only used a single channel opto because it was easier for prototyping. So because the Darlington has an NPN transistor cascaded from the photo transistor, it can pass enough current to drive both the LED and the nand IC? I will still need a pull down resistor on the logic input though yes? I was planning on replacing LED with resistor once I’d done some design verification, it was just a simple way to check that the optocoupler were driving properly.

Comment: The Earth is a return path and equal path to Neutral. If one or two phases are connected and these phases are below the Neutral / Earth potential then current will return to Earth.

Comment: @Jasen yes I know that. The full question of mine: `I’m putting together a pilot light for some 3ø switch gear` - what's that then?

Comment: @justme, thank you for your response. So even though the earth is connected to phase via wye, it will still flow backwards through the diode? If phase potential is lower that neutral/earth I have bigger problems no? Is there another/better way to detect if an earth or neutral wire are open circuit?

Comment: Well I don't know what your wye really is but just a node on the schematics. If L1 is -325V, and L2 and L3 are disconnected, wye node will be negative for sure and only current paths will be from 0V Neutral to wye and 0V PE to wye. It does not flow backwards, only forward via diode.

Comment: Wye is ostensibly equivalent to the star point in a transformer. In your example, you’ve effectively described a single phase supply. Generally speaking the neutral is lower impedance than the PE and would be the preferred return path. The only current that should flow in the PE of my circuit is the current required to switch the opto. Keep in mind please that this is only an end point monitor and in the event 2 phases and or neutral/earth were open circuit, the LED would be displaying a fault condition anyway.

Comment: Yes, it can **draw** enough current from 12V ( or 5V is better)  to drive both the LED and the CMOS 4xxx series? . It is better to put LED on output and Pull DOWN with transistor then 1K + LED leakage is adequate for CMOS pullup. to Vdd-Vf or 9~10V. You can also use 5V for Vdd  the you can use 74HC series CMOS etc which may be more common avail.

Comment: @Andyaka  it seems to be a bunch of indicators for power connections.

Comment: @Jasen maybe someone else needs to have a shot at what it is then because, between you and I, we're not getting anywhere.

Comment: @Andyaka, yes it’s basically indicators for 3 phase equipment. Idea of the ganged flash is to alert to a fault condition which is vague enough to warrant fault finding. Thanks to the help here though, I think I’ve come up with a similarly different approach :)

Answer (score 1):

Transistor optocouplers have a property called "current transfer ratio" this says how much current you can expect on the output for a given input current.

Typically this number is pretty terrible, maybe 10%.
So you should not connect LEDs directly to the optocouplers but instead amplifiy the optocoupler output first

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmo7Rp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yhe problem is virtually no current flows through the opto transistor. Re-arranging the resistor would allow some current to flow. The cmos logic doesn’t need much current, so i see no reason to add another bjt.

Comment: Thank you Jasen and Kartman, When I look an optocoupler I see a relay. Obviously that’s the wrong comparison to make. By putting the resistor on the gnd, and the output on the collector side, won’t I be inverting the output?

Comment: Kartman would you mind elaborating on the resistor rearrange?

Comment: @Kartman: are you talking to me or is that comment in the wrong place.  if no current flows how do the LEDs light?

Comment: @jasen, my point is that your circuit is superfluous as fixing the root cause would solve the problem.

Comment: don't feel constrained by my post. feel free to make your own answer

Answer (score 1):

There are many opto's to choose from. A quad opto doesn't cost any more and saves space.  This version has high CTR current gain >600% and is optimized for 1mA input.

I chose the R values to share the kV noise immunity and power dissipation. for 250V RMS rated 1/4W parts.  They act as a current limiter and fuses (in case of lightning) , regardless of rectifier load.   Each phase draws 1/4 W.

It works better without Zeners as the higher voltage reduces the % ripple, but a reverse signal diode (1N4148 type) was added for reverse protection just in a case of input high voltage transient fault.
To finish. drag the filter Cap into position.

Without the filter cap, it is a ZCS *zero crossing switch* pulse circuit and with the cap chosen has a latency of a few cycles.  Reducing the value of C can detect voltage sag with a pulse. Adjust according to desired Vmin.  There is no need to illuminate modern ultrabright 5mm LEDs (> 5000 mcd 30 deg) with 20 mA. While 10% min or  2mA is suggested and 10 mA is very bright although these opto-drivers can pulse 50 mA.

Your 12V and choice of 45 yr old technology, so the logic may be replaced with 74HCxx series 5V logic, if you have 5V.

[Interactive Proof of concept.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0Y2CMBOJyWoBwgCyQGwCY4cBmI-OAVjQT0wRHInKw3IFMBaOOAKADcQieEHjAZBIOJkzgJ9CCQSRMXPOVo4EavBgi7I5bgBNh5HBKkCw0uAHYzREIdYAzAIYBXADYAXIybMiYlYSdgKOLh4%20fng0IQGm5tIOTm5evsYx1qGqAaJhKZG%20AO7CsbYBsTng3CVEweUCInHVJZn%20jRBVYDX0OBAN5KEN3QBOHc2kGMMSsN0AHliYDhSMOFPkDtZCADIAKgBq7GiY5AA6AM4XFwDCuwBKAHw4FwCK7q6G3GNVktYWvzJMDZYF92oFEsI8hAgSDvL1OnlBrkdLJ2GBIHAiBRECQKJgRKo4FAcOQ8H1geQEFxMX0iapwqkosZlPEzCzmkICmkepgcNIquyutxMGAbFg%20c11M0eABzejZWJI4QimSjeVmAZDbQyOAgu7qkAIMxKtC6QH9IRm9EGEq8-l5O3tbq2wjtSZOnmuhqOho8WprN1NIUAB3GDUE-TgQiJuh6SoafP6oTVAPB4nB0OBMFBAIB4gBmZBcojgc6Nktwm4AGNxnUkk0iMcZOR9Kg28gOGLJJAbFHgQQcMRJDZSFAYDxCEJ3d6vdkGYV2J5WMYY6roH6BAHw1uLM6DYghPHk9xJwajfvtZyImlF8vZFb18KwA5xJgpn0JFGZHgbAB9Pm-mAv4iCOaC-oQQHonAgHgb%20pgANZPi%20FYQcw35-gBf6YloOCAdA454bA0FAcRkAxAgWIMFGCgUZIOBISAODls0pqdCq-REL%20YG4W%20NiYMBkEYnB4HcOcm5TBY7IFrIbieOcrCehqoRSbuDElq%20b6GmYbH-vxJFEJSjYCXhxEiSKDjsOmKrnnWMgIL%20ggOb%20IoIGBIiEfApiqDBPDmSA7CaW0prCGgKJAY5QF4AgUh4A5RCKMoUZqEamhWLF6JETB6UOQxAUYNoGDBQZFbhbFWEGfiGEiiZPl4fgBhAA)

[image]

Drag the cap up into the position to go from ZCS pulse mode to RMS 'OK' mode.

Negative logic (active low) is commonly used as the normal mode.  Your logic may add an a inverter or consider NOR Gates using active low or whatever. There are better ways to do this.

Feel free to short out series LED which won't affect performance.  (CC from 47k x4)  and use thumbwheel over parts to change any values.  Refresh page to start over , or use UNDO. ctrl-z.

This is shown for 240V 50 Hz for my pals over the pond.

T.S.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the comprehnsive response Tony! Would an opto like and HCPL3700 be a better choice? It has a darlington output, a bridge rectifier built in, and I can easily buffer the output with a cap accross pins 2&3. The added cost would likely pay for itself in reduced component count and build time.

Comment: THe component count is higher and input current is 3.5mA each instead of 1mA.  You could use this inexpensive 3 phase bridge instead.  https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30559.pdf